# SSL cert from lets encrypt with nginx proxy for backend api and frontend SPA

Tags: http, ssl, nginx, https, certificate

I am trying to get an SSL cert set up for me newly created website.

- I have purchased the domain from Domains.com

  - I do NOT have LetsEncrypt Free SSL or Enforce SSL turned on. Should I?
  - I have the domain set to stealthily redirect to the IPv4 address
- I have my backend (ASP.NET Core) on the server set up behind my nginx proxy

  - This isn't always running when I try step 7 in the guide, should it be?
  - I haven't configured this for SSL yet
- I have my frontend SPA (Vue.js) static files on the server for nginx to serve
- I have nginx installed and configured
- I have installed certbot from the guide [here](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntufocal-nginx) (this fails on step 7)
- I am running Ubuntu 20.04 in an AWS Lightsail environment

  - I have ports 80 and 443 open for TCP traffic
- I have firewall rules set up with ufw

**Currently my problem is that when I run certbot, it fails on step 7 from the above guide. And now when I go to my website, it automatically redirects from http to https and proceeds to fail loading the page.** I've tried changing the `listen 80` to `listen 443` but that doesn't seem to work. I've also tried placing a test file as suggested [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certbot-unable-to-pass-challenge-dns-a-aaaa-records-not-present-for-domain/34121/2) at `/home/ubuntu/client/dist/.well-known/acme-challenge/test` but for some reason it doesn't let me curl it over http. `curl -ikL http://yabberon.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test`. I also may have some weird DNS things still cached?

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx

Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: yabberon.com
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate numbers separated by commas and/or spaces, or leave input
blank to select all options shown (Enter 'c' to cancel): 1
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for yabberon.com
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain yabberon.com
http-01 challenge for yabberon.com
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: yabberon.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://yabberon.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/oUvNS8hFjexeb2bqhUyeQ5jrEQZFetheOjgjhkryAnA
   [66.96.162.142]: "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html>\r\n\r\n    <head>\r\n
   <title>404 Error - Page Not Found</title>\r\n        <style>\r\n
   #ad_frame"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

nginx config located at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` (the only file I've touched manually for nginx)

```
server {
    listen        80;

    server_name   yabberon.com *.yabberon.com;

    location / {
        root    /home/ubuntu/client/dist;
        index   index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    # listen   80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server deferred;
    return   444;
}
```

Ufw:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I can include anything else that's relevant too, but I think this is sufficient.

Comment: If you use `curl -I` you will notice that an Apache server is responding. You need to sort out your DNS first.

Comment: @RichardSmith I don't believe I have an apache server running on my instance? Does this mean that my domain provider is catching the request somehow? Previously (before I started doing the SSL stuff) I was able to hit my web server with curl just fine and also load my fronted. What do you mean sort out my DNS? I'm not sure what's wrong with it.